# Can't find the problem after debugging the code

Tags: c, function, debugging

When debugging the following code, The debugger point to the line(The line that I commented it out in the last function "printResults" below), But couldn't figure out what is the problem and why the debugger point to that line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 256


void swap(char** a, char** b) {
    char* temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

char* getLongestString(char** strings, int size) {
    char* max = strings[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (strlen(max) < strlen(strings[i])) {
            max = strings[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

void sortStrings(char** strings, int size) {
    bool changed = true;
    while (changed) {
      changed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
          if (strcmp(strings[i], strings[i + 1]) >= 0) {
            swap(&strings[i], &strings[i + 1]);
            changed = true;
          }
        }
    }
}

int readSize() {
  int size = 0;
  printf("Enter number of strings:\n");
  scanf("%d", &size);
  return size;
}

void printResults(char** words, int size) {
    char* longest = getLongestString(words, size);
    printf("The longest word is: %s\n", longest);
    sortStrings(words, size);
    //printf("The maximal word lexicographically is: %s\n", words[size]);
    printf("The minimal word lexicographically is: %s\n", words[0]);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and post your entire code. We need to see how `printResults` is called. At a guess, if `size` is the number of elements in `words`, then `words[size]` is one _beyond_ the end of the array [and it could have a random value that causes a segfault]. You'd need `words[size - 1]` instead

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line

```
printf("The maximal word lexicographically is: %s\n", words[size]);
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the last valid element in an array is at index `size-1` but you index the array using `size`. In other words - an out of bounds access.

So change to

```
printf("The maximal word lexicographically is: %s\n", words[size - 1]);
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

BTW:

This line

```
if (strcmp(strings[i], strings[i + 1]) >= 0) {
```

seems to open up for an endless loop in case two strings are identical. You probably don't want `>=` but only `>`

Comment: When I modifiy this and run the program in debugger(using gdb in bsah) then enter the "bt" command, I get "No Stack"....!!!

Comment: @D.A you haven't shown how you call the function and how you define the array. So there can be a bug in that code. So you need to post that code as well. Here is a working example. https://ideone.com/OPYzRL

Answer (score 0):

Think that the deceleration of array  when you declare an array you do not count index 0  as first element
but when you using the address of that data first index get's in consideration for example,lets declare an array

```
int x[5];
```

by doing that you are telling the compiler to allocate 5 available integer memory address.So you will get an allocated area and  your size will be 5.
Lets assume the compiler gives you 5 address starting from 0x20000580--0x20000584
by writing

```
x[0] = data0;// you are writing data to  the address of 0x20000580-> data0             
x[1]= data1;// 0x20000581-> data1 
...
x[4]= data4 //0x20000584->data4
```

so in your case when you try to write x[size] which is x[5] you are trying to access 
   an un-allocated area and this cause hard fault
    interrupt and you will face unhand-led exception.